# Why the error no match for 'operator==', when using `std::find`?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, stdstring

I am using `std::find` to check a string isn't in `std::vector<std::vector<string>>`

Error:

```
no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' and 'const char [6]')
```

Isn't it the type doesn't match?

```cpp
vector< vector< string>>data;

if(find(data.begin(), data.end(), "START") == data.end()){

    printf("Missing \"START\"\n");
    return true;`
```

Comment: You have a vector of vectors, not a vector of strings. Your Compiler said that it is unable to find a string in vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message has been well explained in the other answer. I would like to provide a solution to the problem.

As you are trying to find, *if any of the `std::string` element in the vector of vector matches to `"START"`*, you could use standard algorithm *[std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)* in combination with a *[unary predicate](http://www.drdobbs.com/effective-standard-c-library-unary-predi/184403777)* which returns `std::find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), str) != vec.cend()`; where `vec` is the each rows of the vector of vectors. **[See a demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2Cewdsb2SbMWEyQk)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isFound(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& data, const std::string &str)
{
    const auto found_in_vector = [&str](const std::vector<std::string> & vec)-> bool {
        return std::find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), str) != vec.cend(); // if found
    };

    if (std::any_of(data.cbegin(), data.cend(), found_in_vector))
    {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
        return true;
    }

    std::cout << "Missing \""<< str << " \"\n";
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
    std::vector<std::string> test{ "START","test" }; 
    data.emplace_back(test);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isFound(data, std::string{ "START" } );
}
```

Comment: `(data.begin(), data.end(), [](vector<string>vec)->bool{return find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "START") == vec.end();}) ` can i write the labda like this?

Comment: but when i add`std::vector<std::string>test{"START","test"};
    data.push_back(test);`it still false

Comment: @Alvin_Kirin Sorry.. There was typo in `std::find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), str) == vec.cend();`, should have been `std::find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), str) != vec.cend();`, will update the answer!

Comment: got it Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The error is triggered, because you've got a "vector of vectors of strings", i.e. there's one dimension too much. Define `data` using `std::vector<std::string>` instead and it will work.

#### But why does the error talk about a missing operators?

When you use `std::find()`, it's typically implemented as a macro or templated function, which does the actual work, rather than a precompiled runtime function somewhere in a library. This allows the compiler full optimization based on the actual types of your parameters.

What it actually does - since your container is a class - is trying to find a special member function, `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::operator==(const char*)`. It's not directly implemented this way, typically a template instead, but that's not important here. The important fact is it won't find any version of `operator==()` with an argument that is somehow able to accept the string passed, either directly or through conversion. Reason for this is that your vector contains vectors, so the only valid argument would be another vector of strings.

Comment: so data.end() doesn't return a vector and it just returns a member of vector?

Comment: @Alvin_Kirin It returns a position past the last element.